# List items should create sharepoint group

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I am facing one problem from last one week. I have one list having clients name. So when i add new client to the list then sharepoint user group should be created with client name as group name.

So is it possible to do that? if yes then how can i do this?

Comment: please refer to [ask] page to see how to ask properly. Also, you should ask on [sharepoint.se].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that using three possibles methods :

1. Design a workflow that is fired on item creation and which is attached to the list
2. Create an EventReveiver to handle ItemAdded event, and create the SP group
3. Modify the new form of the list. I don't recommend this way because if customers are created from another place, the logic won't be fired.

Another way to solve such problems, but it requires more background of your need, is to split your data into several site collections, one for each customer. Each site collection can have a "Customer" group (maybe created from a site template), which contains the customer. As each site collections have distinct users and groups, it can avoid cross customer data leaking (due to misconfiguration of authorizations).

Comment: I think second method is good. I am working with sharepoint GUI. So can you tell me how can i create SP group in visual studio. I tried two-three ways but couldn't get my answer. Any link of related post would be appreciable.

Comment: what are you calling SharePoint GUI ? Such requirement has to be done using code ...

Comment: [Google](http://www.google.fr/search?q=create+spgroup) and [SPGroupCollection.Add Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spgroupcollection.add.aspx)